# creating a close button for a div using jquery, ajax and close the div without page refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I have created a div with a close  button for a cookie display pop up. Cookie creation is worked perfectly. But once I click on the close button, the div closes and page is refreshed. Then again display that close div. 
 This is my code for cookie creation, I use ajax to create the cookie. This is for a wordpress site.
If some one can help me to add the close button to close the pop up without refresh the web page . Thanks in advance.

JavaScript
This is in  custom.js File

```
// ========================= Ajax for Set cookie =======================
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#cookie_btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
        type:'json',
        action: 'setCookiePopup'
           }; 
       jQuery.post(ajax_url.ajaxurl, data, function(response) { 
          var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
          if (res.result) {
            $('#cookie_modal_body').remove();
            // $('#cookie_modal_body').slideToggle();
          }
         });
     });
});


// ===============Add close button to cookie div==================
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#close_img_btn_anchor').click(function(e){
            $('#cookie_modal_body').hide();
    });
});
```

This is in functions.php file

```
//======================== Set Cookie ===================================
function setCookiePopup() {

    $cookie_name = "Newcookie";
    $cookie_value = "coojieValue";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 3600, "/");

    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'true'));
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_setCookiePopup', 'setCookiePopup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setCookiePopup', 'setCookiePopup');


//=================  Short Code to set cookie pop-up =====================

add_shortcode('setCookiePopupShortCode','setCookiePopupShortCode');


function setCookiePopupShortCode(){
    $cookie_name = "Newcookie";
    var_dump($cookie_name);

     if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

        $popup  = '<div class="" id="cookie_modal_body">';  
        $popup .= '<p id="cookie_text_custom">We use cookies to track usage and preferences. </p>';
        // $popup .= '<p id="cookie_links_custom"> <a id="cookie_policy_link" href="'.site_url().'/cookie-policy.html" target="_blank">Read our cookie policy </a> or <a id="cookie_btn" href="#"> close  <b class="close_img" id="close_img_btn">X</b> </a> </p>'; 

        $popup .= '<p id="cookie_links_custom"><a id="cookie_btn" href="#"> Accept </a> or  <a id="cookie_policy_link" href="'.site_url().'/cookie-policy.html" target="_blank">Read our cookie policy </a></p>';

        $popup .= '<button class="close_img" id="close_img_btn"><a href="" id="close_img_btn_anchor">X</a></button>';                        
        $popup .= '</div>'; 

        echo $popup;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. make the button `type="button"` 2. remove the LINK from INSIDE the button: `$popup .= '<button type="button" class="close_img" id="close_img_btn">X</button>';` using `$('#close_img_btn')`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @mplungjan, Thank you very much, I missed it